# Setting the timestamp for authentication cookie in ASP identity so session don't expire so quick

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies

I am having some troubles setting the timestamp for the cookie in my web application.
The session ends to quick and i wish to increase the time before the session expires.
I have tried to edit the Startup.Auth.cs file but i dont seem to have any effect. Here i what it looks like now.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(600),
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login.aspx"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(600),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```

eventhough i have increased the time in here i dont seem to be working. I dont know if it gets ignored? The session last about 30 min before it expires

Do any of you have an idear why the time limit is so short?